# SQL Server : dynamically change SQL Server in SELECT statement based on a variable

Tags: sql-server

I have a weird use case that is unncessarily convoluted to explain, but the end result is that I use a much longer version of this query repeatedly throughout the day:

```
--DECLARE @Vendor int = 1 --Vendor1
--DECLARE @Vendor int = 2 --Vendor2
DECLARE @Vendor int = 3 --Vendor3

DECLARE @DatabaseName sysname;
DECLARE @SqlScript nvarchar(MAX);

SELECT @DatabaseName =
    CASE @Vendor
        WHEN 1 THEN 'VENDOR1_DB'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'VENDOR2_DB'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'VENDOR3_db'
    END

IF @DatabaseName IS NULL
    RAISERROR ('Unknown Vendor (%d) specified', 16, 1, @vendor);

SET @SqlScript = N'USE ' + QUOTENAME(@DatabaseName) + N';

SELECT stuff
FROM [dbo].[table]
    WHERE vendor_key = @Vendor
    AND create_date > convert(varchar,getdate(),112)
';

EXECUTE sp_executesql
    @SqlScript
    , N'@Vendor varchar(50)'
    , @vendor=@vendor;
GO
```

I comment in whichever vendor I need to run it for.  The reason is so that I can have one query that I can run when connected to a SQL server and it will auto select which database to use based on which vendor I want to look up (Each vendor has their own database.)  I have to run this constantly throughout the day, so this is just the easiest way for me to do it.

The thing that I'm missing though, is that we have 20 or so servers, and each server has 5-10 databases on it.  So I'm connected to Server1 to query Vendor1, Vendor2, or Vendor3, but I have different versions of this query written for every server I connect to.  So for example, this query is saved as Server1.sql, and I'd have another query saved as Server2.sql and it would have the info for Vendor4, Vendor5 and Vendor6 in the case/declare.

Is there something similar to

```
N'USE ' + QUOTENAME(@DatabaseName) + N'
```

that I can have it dynamically select the SQL Server?

This is a completely imaginary script that demonstrates what I'm talking about (Sorry, I'm not great at this)

```
--DECLARE @Vendor int = 1 --Vendor1
--DECLARE @Vendor int = 4 --Vendor4
DECLARE @Vendor int = 8 --Vendor8

DECLARE @DatabaseName sysname;
DECLARE @ServerName sysname; --?
DECLARE @SqlScript nvarchar(MAX);

SELECT @DatabaseName =
    CASE @Vendor
        WHEN 1 THEN 'VENDOR1_DB'
        WHEN 4 THEN 'VENDOR4_DB'
        WHEN 8 THEN 'VENDOR8_DB'
    END

SELECT @ServerName = 
    CASE @Vendor
        WHEN 1 THEN 'SERVER1.BLA.BLA'
        WHEN 4 THEN 'SERVER2.BLA.BLA'
        WHEN 8 THEN 'SERVER3.BLA.BLA'
    END

SET @SqlScript = N'USE ' + QUOTENAME(@DatabaseName) + N';
N'USE ' + QUOTENAME(@ServerName) + N'; --I know that this doesn't actually work

SELECT stuff
FROM [dbo].[table]
    WHERE vendor_key = @Vendor
    AND create_date > convert(varchar,getdate(),112)
';

EXECUTE sp_executesql
    @SqlScript
    , N'@Vendor varchar(50)'
    , @vendor=@vendor;
GO
```

Comment: Any chance that there's one server that has linked server connections to all of the others? If there is (or could be), this would be doable. If not, we'll have to wait for somebody smarter than me to come along. Luckily, there's a lot of that going on here.

Comment: Can you create [linked servers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/linked-servers-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017)? If so, then you could run this script and simply use the fully qualified name. Another option would be a [central management server](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2008/08/sql-server-2008s-new-central-management-server/)

Comment: I should add that with CMS, You can run a query on a "group" of servers and it will execute on all of them, which is why I suggested this option. Naturally, the DB names would need to match.

Comment: As Eric asked, if you have them all linked, have you considered creating a temporary table with the database name as Column 1 then the script for each database in Column 2?

If that is setup, you just have to run a case statement to specify which script to use for that particular query?

Comment: Also as you mentioned, you state that you "comment in whichever vendor I need to run it for". Please provide a sample of the query you would to comment?

Comment: @Birel, with regard to the "commenting", I think she's just referring to the `DECLARE`s at the top of each query where she's changing the database parameters.